# How to create slide animation in MotionLayout with constraints?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

MotionLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0c0"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="right text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="left text"
        android:textColor="#33691E" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c00"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="918dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00c"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="right text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="left text"
        />
</FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Scene:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

    <Constraint android:id="@id/left_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:alpha="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bar"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/right_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/left_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="1"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/right_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
<!-- <OnClick app:targetId="@id/bar" app:clickAction="toggle" />-->
    <OnSwipe app:touchAnchorId="@id/bar" app:dragDirection="dragLeft" />
</Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

[image: Current animation]

I need to apply translate animation like this using old animation:

```
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%"
               android:toXDelta="-100%"
               android:duration="150"
    />
```

The current animation is a resize of a dissapearing view but I need translation animation, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it, it is not easy to say at least:
To achieve a slide animation without resizing of content you need
2 offscreen layouts which recreate imaginable place where visible content will be pushed or pulled.

The first offscreen buffer(positioned to the left of a visible layout) will be mirrored visible layout(not a full copy but blueprint of top level containers).

The second offscreen buffer(positioned to the right of the visible layout)  will be a copy of visible layout.

Important: invisible part of a layout must be constrained as it is visible to user to avoid resize animation from 0 to a target size

It is hard to describe, but easier to show a result:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

<View
    android:id="@+id/off_screen_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


<View
    android:id="@+id/off_screen_left_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/off_screen_left_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/off_screen_right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/off_screen_right_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <View android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/off_screen_right_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0c0"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="right text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="left text"
        android:textColor="#33691E" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c00"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">
    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00c"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="right text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="left text"
        />
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/off_screens">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_left_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/off_screen_left"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_left_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/off_screen_left_bar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/off_screen_left"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_right_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/off_screen_right"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/off_screen_right_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/off_screen_right"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/off_screen_right_bar"
        />
</ConstraintSet>


<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"
    app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/off_screens">

    <Constraint android:id="@id/left_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/bar"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/right_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/off_screen_right_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/off_screen_right_content"/>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end" app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/off_screens">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/left_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/off_screen_left_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/off_screen_left_content"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/right_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
    <OnSwipe app:touchAnchorId="@id/bar" 
             app:dragDirection="dragLeft" />
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Result animation:
[image: slide animation]

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to share your findings on github! I had a similar use case and your solution allowed me to get mine to work with some modifications :) It's really weird how hard it is to make match_parent layout keep it's original size when animating it using motionlayout